# Intellisense for node_modules paths in angular-cli.json?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular-cli, node-modules

In VS Code, is there a way to enable intellisense/auto completion for `node_modules` paths in the angular-cli.json?

This is what I get (angular-cli.json):

[image]

This is what I want (tsconfig.json):

[image]

My VS Code version is 1.8.1. I tried the following plugins without success:

- Path Intellisense
- npm Intellisense
- Node.js Modules Intellisense

For some reason they don't seem to work in the angular-cli.json.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`Path Intellisense`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense) extension works fine for me (VSCode version 1.28.2):

[image]

(*The base path is diffent because `angular-cli.json` was moved and renamed to `angular.json` in Angular 6.*)

Answer (score -2):

you can use **`Relative Path Extension`**

please visit link for documentation

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jakob101.RelativePath

you can change the start command from `Ctr+Shift+H` to `f2`

**step:**

1. In vs code click on settings
2. Click on Keyboard shortcuts
3. Search for Relative Path
4. Change the command to f2

[image: proof pic]